# Pie chart instead of markercluster icons in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization, markerclusterer

I have a requirement where I would need to create a google map with `markers clustering` functionality.

The change here is customising the cluster with the `pie chart` instead of the default cluster.

Say for example,

I have `markers` of different `category` and I need to show the cluster containing the number in each category similar to the one shown in the following links

http://bl.ocks.org/gisminister/10001728

http://www.ilfattoquotidiano.it/patrie-galere-deaths-italian-prisons-since-2002-2012/

but with `google maps`. How can I do this? I have no clue of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first link you gave is in java script, which google map uses. So you just need to modify your code little bit. You can see another example of markercluster right here http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/examples.html

Comment: i need to make the same think. did you find a solution please ?

Comment: Since I had no solution, I edited the Google clusterer js file and achieved it.

Comment: @Logesh would you mind sharing your solution? I also need to implement this feature. Hope to hear from you soon. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had to fulfil the exact same requirement so I solved it by extending the Google Maps Marker Cluster Library. You can download the solution from my GitHub repository: https://github.com/hassanlatif/chart-marker-clusterer

Comment: Hi Hassanlatif, I have tried the example given on your github github.com/hassanlatif/… but it does not seem to work. It only shows the numbers on the map but not the pie chart. Can you please provide me a working example of pie charts on map? It would be really helpful for my project. My mail id is pprajapat@mphrx.com.

Comment: Hi @AnujAneja, sorry I  missed your comment, were you able to make it work?